# Delete all lines before last case of a string

Tags: bash, sed

How would I go about deleting all the lines before the last occurrence of a string. Like if I had a file that looked like

```
Icecream is good
And
Chocolate is good
And
They have lots of sugar
```

If I want all lines after and including the last occurrence of "And" what's the cleanest way to do this? Specifically, I want

```
And
They have lots of sugar
```

I was doing `sed -n -E -e '/And/,$p' file` but I see this gives me the first occurrence.

Comment: Add your desired output for that sample input.

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/And/h;//!H;$!d;x;//p' file
```

Replace anything in the hold space by the line containing `And`. Append all other lines to the hold space. At the end of the file, swap the pattern space for the hold space and print out the result as long it matches the required string `And`.

Comment: Take a look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958584/delete-all-lines-before-last-case-of-a-string#comment49950428_30958584) ;)

Comment: Could you not just do `sed -n '/And/h;H;${x;p}'`

Comment: @User112638726 no. That would double the required string line and also give a false result if the required string did not exist. However `sed -n 'H;/And/h;$x;$//p' file` would also work.

Comment: @potong That gives me `sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown command: `/'`

Comment: @potong can you explain what this does as well please `//!H` ?

Comment: @User112638726 it means if the last regex used does not match then append the pattern space to the hold space.

Comment: @potong cheers do you have any documentation i could look up for it ? Might be other interesting stuff i don't know.

Comment: @User112638726 if you hover the cursor over the tag `sed` you will see a popup , look for the  `info` link in blue at the bottom..

Answer (score 1):

I know that you asked for sed and that Potong provided a good sed solution.  But, for comparison, here is an awk solution:

```
$ awk 's{s=s"\n"$0;} /And/{s=$0;} END{print s;}' file
And
They have lots of sugar
```

How it works:

- `s{s=s"\n"$0;}`

  If the variable `s` is not empty, then add to it the current line, `$0`.
- `/And/{s=$0;}`

  If the current line contains `And`, then set `s` to the current line, `$0`.
- `END{print s;}`

  After we have reached the end of the file, print `s`.

Answer (score -4):

```
$ tac file | awk '!f; /And/{f=1}' | tac
And
They have lots of sugar

$ awk 'NR==FNR{if(/And/)nr=NR;next} FNR>=nr' file file
And
They have lots of sugar
```

Comment: Please provide explanation.

Comment: No, that's very basic stuff you can get from reading a page or 2 of any awk documentation but I'll be happy to answer any questions anyone has after putting a small amount of effort into figuring it out for themselves.

Comment: Who cares how basic it is. As someone with so many points you should be well familiar with SO etiquette. Your question was flagged for quality. Since it's correct all I did was leave a comment. You can't expect people to just "read a page or 2" .. if you could SO wouldn't be nearly as popular. Fact is, correct or not, your answer sucks. You should fix it.